# Python 3 entry digits only with error print in another label

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to codding in general. I have found a code for a function which restricts users of entering anything but digits in entry field but I can't assign the function to entry object.
I have tree problems.

1. I can't assign function to entry.
2. I want error print message to show in label "A".
3. Pressing "Enter" multiple times execute "def doit(FFF)" multiple times on top of each other, so I want to restrict pressing it more than one time.

I have been trying for the past 3 days but I keep failing.

```
from tkinter import *

def doit(FFF):
     ...

def val():
API = IN.get()
while True:
    try:
        API = int(input())
    except ValueError:
        print('Not an integer')
        continue
    else:
        return API
        break



root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x200")


IN = Entry(root)
IN.bind("<Return>", val, lambda _:doit(FFF))
IN.pack(side=LEFT, fill="both", expand=True)

A = Label(root, fg="red")
A.pack(side=LEFT)
B = Button(root, text="START", fg="black", command=lambda:doit(FFF))
B.pack(side=RIGHT)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: you can unbind `<Return>` to stop multiple executions. Or create variable ie. `already_pressed = True` to control it on your own.

Comment: `A['text'] = "Error!!!"`

Comment: `input` gets user input from the *terminal*; you can't use that for GUI widgets. Can you explain more what you want your program to look like / do? Not how you want it to do it; but describe the user experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example

`is_integer()` checks only if `text` is integer number and returns `True/False` so it can be used in many places.

`<KeyRelease>` executes `validate()` after every keypress (or rather key release) and `validate()` uses `is_integer()` to check text in `Entry` (`event.widget` gives access to widget to which was `bind()` event) and changes text in `Label`.

`Button` executes function `run_it()` which uses `is_integer()` to check if `Entry` has correct integer (to make sure) or you have to check if `Entry` is not empty. If `Entry` has no correct integer then it changes text in `Label` and ends function.

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def run_it():

    # you can check it again to make sure
    text = e.get()
    if not is_integer(text):
        l['text'] = "You can't run it"
        return

    # do what you want
    l['text'] = 'Running ...'

def validate(event):
    #text = e.get()
    text = event.widget.get()
    if is_integer(text):    
        l['text'] = ''
    else:
        l['text'] = 'Not an integer'

def is_integer(text):
    try:
        value = int(text)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

e = tk.Entry(root)
e.pack()
#e.bind("<Return>", validate)
e.bind("<KeyRelease>", validate)

l = tk.Label(root)
l.pack()

b = tk.Button(root, text="START", command=run_it)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Furas, this is working perfectly. Just pressing Enter does not start "run_it()" but I will figure that out. It looks like I have to learn a bit more.

Comment: if you what start `runt_it` when you click in `Entry` then `bind(`<Return>`, run_it) but `bind executes it with agument `event` so you will need `def run_it(event=None):` Because `command=` executes `run_it` without arguments so I assign default value `None` to `event`.

Comment: if you want to use `Enter` with button then `bind` to button. You can also bind to `root` and it can execute even when you doesn't select `Entry` or `Button`

Comment: It is me again. Can I assign colour to  L['text'] = ' ' so it is green if it is saying "running" and red if "Not an integer"?

Comment: "text" means text , not color. When you create label then you can set color `Label(root,  bg="green")` and it means you can change it later with  `L['bg'] = 'red'` or `L.config( bg="red" )` - see parameters in [Label.config()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm#Tkinter.Label.config-method)

Comment: Thanks, it is working. I did it in two lines `L['fg'] = 'red' , L['text'] = 'Not an integer '` and then `L['fg'] = 'green' , L['text'] = 'Running '`